# CSS margin coding

Tags: kindle

Can't seems to get the top margin in my dedication page. Any one can help with the below coding? Appreciate all help rendered.

```
      <p style="_@page {margin-top: 20 !important;p>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code example I cannot see the unit of the margin. I guess you mean 20 pixels, other units would be too big. So you should write **20px**.

But I think that 20 pixels will render differently on different readers. You might want to try units relative to the font. It might be **1.5em** or **2em**. But you will have to take into account that whatever you put some old readers will ignore it.